# GitHub Actions: How to access to the log of current build via Terminal

Tags: github, build, github-actions

I'm trying to get familiar with Github Actions. I have configured my workflow in a way, that every time I push my code to GitHub, the code will automatically be built and pushed to heroku.

How can I access the build log information in terminal without going to github.com?

Answer (score 8):

With the latest [`cli/cli` tool named `gh`](https://cli.github.com/) (1.9.0+), you can simply do
(from your terminal, *without* going to `github.com`):

```
gh run view <jobId> --log 
# or
gh run view <jobId> --log-failed
```

See "[Work with GitHub Actions in your terminal with GitHub CLI](https://github.blog/2021-04-15-work-with-github-actions-in-your-terminal-with-github-cli/)"

> With the new **`gh run list`**, you receive an overview of all types of workflow runs whether they were triggered via a push, pull request, webhook, or manual event.
>
> To drill down into the details of a single run, you can use **`gh run view`**, optionally going into as much detail as the individual steps of a job.
>
> For more mysterious failures, you can combine a tool like grep with **`gh run view --log`** to search across a run’s entire log output.
>
> If `--log` is too much information, **`gh run --log-failed`** will output only the log lines for individual steps that failed.
> This is great for getting right to the logs for a failed step instead of having to run `grep` yourself.

And with [GitHub CLI 2.4.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.4.0) (Dec. 2021), `gh run list` comes with a `--json` flag for JSON export.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```sh
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/<github-user>/<repository>/actions/workflows/<workflow.yaml>/runs
```

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/actions#list-workflow-runs

This will return a JSON with the following structure:

```json
{
  "total_count": 1,
  "workflow_runs": [
    {
      "id": 30433642,
      "node_id": "MDEyOldvcmtmbG93IFJ1bjI2OTI4OQ==",
      "head_branch": "master",
      "head_sha": "acb5820ced9479c074f688cc328bf03f341a511d",
      "run_number": 562,
      "event": "push",
      "status": "queued",
      "conclusion": null,
      "workflow_id": 159038,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642",
      "pull_requests": [],
      "created_at": "2020-01-22T19:33:08Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-22T19:33:08Z",
      "jobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/jobs",
      "logs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/logs",
      "check_suite_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/check-suites/414944374",
      "artifacts_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/artifacts",
      "cancel_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/cancel",
      "rerun_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/rerun",
      "workflow_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/workflows/159038",
      "head_commit": {...},
      "repository": {...},
      "head_repository": {...}
  ]
}
```

Access the `jobs_url` with a PAT that has repository admin rights.