# GitHub Actions: How can i access the job logs of current build via API?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-api

I want to get the job logs of a current workflow from Github Actions through a nodejs backend. I know that Github provides an API, to access informations about a workflow like this:

```
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/runs
```

with a response like this:

```json
{
  "total_count": 1,
  "workflow_runs": [
    {
      "id": 30433642,
      "node_id": "MDEyOldvcmtmbG93IFJ1bjI2OTI4OQ==",
      "head_branch": "master",
      "head_sha": "acb5820ced9479c074f688cc328bf03f341a511d",
      "run_number": 562,
      "event": "push",
      "status": "queued",
      "conclusion": null,
      "workflow_id": 159038,
      "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642",
      "html_url": "https://github.com/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642",
      "pull_requests": [],
      "created_at": "2020-01-22T19:33:08Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-01-22T19:33:08Z",
      "jobs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/jobs",
      "logs_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/logs",
      "check_suite_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/check-suites/414944374",
      "artifacts_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/artifacts",
      "cancel_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/cancel",
      "rerun_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/runs/30433642/rerun",
      "workflow_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octo-org/octo-repo/actions/workflows/159038",
      "head_commit": {...},
      "repository": {...},
      "head_repository": {...}
  ]
}
```

From [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954361/github-actions-how-to-access-to-the-log-of-current-build-via-terminal), I learned that you can get more information about the current build logs via the `job_url`, but does this take place in real time? Is there a way to stream the current logs, so i am able to display them on my own webpage?

Background:
I want to trigger a workflow with an HTTP request using [dispatch-event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event) and after that, i want to display the current job logs on my own UI

Comment: AFAIK (from having tried to do this myself), there is no way to get the logs of a _job_ that is currently executing. However, once that job is complete, the logs will be made available for download using that `logs_url` URL.

Answer (score 0):

The `logs_url` attribute can indeed be found in the response of the GitHub API endpoint `GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/workflows/{workflow_id}/runs/{run_id}`, which provides details about individual workflow runs. This URL points to an archive containing the raw logs for the entire workflow run, which includes logs for each job and step executed in the workflow.

However, it's important to note that regardless of whether the repository is public or private, you must be authenticated (usually via a personal access token) to access the API and download logs from the `logs_url`.